# Django: object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: django

I want to update first one record of the database.

This result can be two or more results. This works.

```
TelegramAppUserConfig.objects.filter(user=user).update(json="hoge")
```

This should result just one result. But this doesn't work. `Django: object has no attribute 'update'`

```
TelegramAppUserConfig.objects.filter(user=user).first().update(json="hoge")
TelegramAppUserConfig.objects.filter(user=user)[0].update(json="hoge")
```

How can I code for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with single objects, you can always just use `save()` to persist any changes:

```
config = TelegramAppUserConfig.objects.filter(user=user).first()

config.json = "hoge"
config.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

.update method is callable on queryset not on a single object e.g. TelegramAppUserConfig in your case. To get a queryset containing only the first item you can use `TelegramAppUserConfig.objects.filter(user=user) [0:1]`. So you can update it as

```
TelegramAppUserConfig.objects.filter(user=user) [0:1].update(json="hoge")
```

Comment: looks nice. But I've got an error: `Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken.`